# Delete duplicate files using ant?

Tags: java, ant

Is there a way to delete duplicate files using ant?  Specifically, if I have the same file name in two different output directories, I want to delete it from the second directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I came up with a solution.

```
<target name="delete-duplicates">
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="delete-here" includes="**/*">
            <present targetdir="if-present-here" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```

Comment: Well done Craig.  I presume the only checking the solution does it for matching file-name.  
Did you encounter a way of checking if the files were `identical`? (via size or hash, I guess)