# Can Ant remove _identical_ files from two directories?

Tags: file, ant

I'm aware that Ant can delete files that have matching filenames from two directories. [1].

But, I wish to test for the files being identical - I only want to delete them if they are byte identical copies (or *maybe* identical size would suffice).

Is creating my own Ant task the only way of doing this?

Background: I regularly distribute a zip of data-files.  To save bandwidth, instead I wish to switch to only distributing a delta of the data-files.  To do this, I need to know which files have not changed since the previous release - just identifying new files isn't good enough.

[1]. [Delete duplicate files using ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088338/delete-duplicate-files-using-ant)

Answer (score 1):

Ant has a `different` selector that can be applied to resource collections. It can select files by modified time, content, or both.

Here's an example target demonstrating how it works.

```
<target name="copy-different">
    <delete dir="src_dir" />
    <delete dir="dest_dir" />

    <mkdir dir="src_dir" />
    <mkdir dir="dest_dir" />

    <touch file="src_dir/file1" />
    <touch file="src_dir/file2" />

    <echo file="src_dir/file1" message="identical" />
    <echo file="src_dir/file2" message="different" />

    <touch file="dest_dir/file1" />
    <touch file="dest_dir/file2" />

    <echo file="dest_dir/file1" message="identical" />
    <echo file="dest_dir/file2" message="identical" />

    <copy todir="different" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="src_dir">
            <different targetdir="dest_dir" ignoreFileTimes="true" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Only `file2` will be copied to `dest_dir`.